# Convergence of $\sin(t^n)/\ln(t^n))^n$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that$ \int_{t=0}^{t=1/2} \left(\frac{\sin(t^n)}{\ln(t^n)}\right)^n dt$ converges for any positive integer $n$. I thought about using a comparison test, but I don't know what to compare it to.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Shaun. I added a few of my thoughts, but I am genuinely stuck on this question.

Comment: The integrand is continuous every except at $t = 0$, but the limit as $t \to 0$ is $\frac 0{-\infty} = 0$. So it can be extended to a continuous function over the entire interval.